# How to identify/rename EJB threads for identification in VisualVM for debugging

Tags: jakarta-ee, visualvm

Is there a way to give the threads that run in EJBs a name so they can be identified in the thread list in VisualVM?  Threads call timer (@Timeout) and JMS (onMessage()) methods as well as http servlets methods.

Currently, the threads are given generic names such as:

```
http--0.0.0.0-443-3
or
EJB default - 9
```

I currently use :

```
Thread.currentThread().setName("Checker thread")
```

at the beginning of these methods, but I'm not sure it is always working in VisualVM so am looking for additional ideas.

Comment: @Dharmesh, thanks for the styling edit.

Comment: even you can do by using curly bracket given above the editor and putting code into that while posting questions or answers

Answer (score 0):

In the `@PostConstruct` method of the EJB I use the same `Thread` statement you do.

You might also think about placing it in a class level interceptor and use the [invocation context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/InvocationContext.html) to get the name of the EJB and name the thread accordingly at that point.

Comment: You can't put it in the @PostConstruct and set the name permanently b/c the thread could be reused for a completely different task elsewhere in the container and so the name will be misleading when looking at a stack dump. I didn't say, but I have to reset the name to its original name before leaving the method.

Comment: @AlJo that hasn't been my experience with glassfish. What container do you use?

Comment: JBoss. It's certainly probable since the threads come from a thread pool - for the usual cases - and there's no guarantee which one from the pool will be chosen to run a particular method each time.